# How do we deduce that a=b?

Tags: number-theory

If $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} \in \mathbb{Z}$, I want to show that $a=b$. After that, I want to show that $a=1$ or $a=2$.

I have thought the following so far.

Since $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} \in \mathbb{Z}$, it follows that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=k, \text{ for some } k\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

Then $b+a=kab$.

Suppose that $a \neq b$. Then $\exists$ some prime $p$ such that $p \mid a$ and some prime $q \neq p$ such that $q \mid b$.

Then $p \mid b+a$ and $p \mid a$. Thus $p \mid b$. So we get that $p \cdot q \mid b$.

In the same way, we get that $p \cdot q \mid a$.

Therefore, we get that $p \cdot q \mid a \cdot b$.

Can we use the above in order to deduce that $a=b$ ?

Comment: `and some prime` $q\neq p $ `such that` $q|b $- you can't assume this.

Comment: Why? @taritgoswami

Comment: $b=a(kb-1)$, so $a|b$, and by symmetry $b|a$ and therefore $a=b$ .

Comment: @Evinda What if $b|a$?

Comment: "Suppose that $a \neq b$. Then $\exists$ some prime $p$ such that $p \mid a$ and some prime $q \neq p$ such that $q \mid b$." No, that is wrong, e.g. $12=a \neq b=18$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is much simpler to use inequalities. We have $\frac 1 a \leq 1$ and $\frac 1 b \leq 1$ so $\frac 1 a +\frac 1 b\leq 2$. If $\frac 1 a +\frac 1 b$ is an integer then it  must be $1$ or $2$. Also, if $a>2$ or $b >2$ we get $\frac 1 a +\frac 1 b <1.5 <2$ so we  mjust have $a \leq 2$ and $b \leq 2$. You can now finish the proof easily.

Comment: Why doesn't this work always?

Comment: What about negatives ?

Comment: But here it is given that $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. @YvesDaoust

Comment: @Evinda: oooops, I didn't see that $+$.

Comment: Ok... But if we suppose that $a>2$ or $b>2$, we get that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}<1.5$, which is not a contradiction, since it ca be that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=1$. Or am I wrong?

Comment: $\frac 1 a +\frac 1 b=1$ is possible only when $a=b=1$ because $a$ and $b$ are positive inergers.

Comment: This can only happen if $a=b=2$, so we have a contradiction, right?

Comment: Sorry about the typo. I meant $a=b=2$.

Comment: I see... After that, we distinguish the cases $a=1$ and $a=2$. For $a=1$ we can only have $b=1$ and for $a=2$ we can only have $b=2$. Thus we deduce that $a=b$ and $a=1$ or $a=2$, right? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Exactly. That is what I though you would figure out by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand:
$$b+a=kab \Rightarrow (ak-1)(bk-1)=1 \Rightarrow \\
\begin{cases}ak-1=1 \\ bk-1=1\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}a=\frac 2k\ge 1 \\ b=\frac 2k\ge 1\end{cases} \Rightarrow k\le 2.$$
On the other hand: 
$$a,b\ge 1 \Rightarrow \frac1a +\frac1b=k>0.$$

Thus: $k=1$ and $k=2$.

Comment: How do you establish $(ak-1)(bk-1)=1$ ??

Comment: Right, my bad .

Answer (score 1):

Write $a=dx$ and $b=dy$ where $d=\gcd(a,b)$ and $x,y$ are relatively prime. Then

$$ab\mid a+b\implies d^2xy\mid d(x+y) \implies dxy\mid x+y \implies x\mid x+y$$ $$\implies x\mid (x+y)-x \implies x\mid y \implies x=1$$

With the same logic we get $y=1$.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG $a\le b$.

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
&a=1&a=2&a>2
\\\hline b=1&\color{green}1&-&-
\\b=2&\frac32&\color{green}1&-
\\b>2&1<1+\frac1b<2&0<\frac12+\frac1b<1&0<\frac1a+\frac1b<1
\end{array}$$

Comment: But what happens if only one of the $a,b$ is greater than $2$ ?

Comment: @Evinda: see my final answer.

Comment: I see... We could also firstly show that $a \leq 2$ and $b \leq 2$, and then distinguish the cases $a=1$ and $a=2$. Then for $a=1$ we can only have $b=1$ and for $a=2$ we can only have $b=2$. And thus we deduce that $a=b$ then $a=1$ or $2$, right? @YvesDaoust

Comment: @Evinda: by my answer, I want to show a systematic approach, which guarantees that no case is forgotten. The rightmost two cases on the last row could have been merged, but I want to avoid any "smartness".

Comment: Yes, because as you did it, we haven't rejected the cases $a>2$ and $b>2$, right?

Comment: @Evinda: $\mathbb N^2$ is covered exhaustively.

Comment: Ok... And isn't that done with the way I wrote above? @YvesDaoust

Comment: @Evinda: the point is to be systematic. Million other approaches are possible.

Comment: Ok, so using the way I wrote, we have to add what we get symmetrically distinguishing cases for $b$...

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest much easier approach:

You only need to check few cases:

Case 1: If $a=1$ then $\frac{1}{b}$ must be an integer which is only possible if $b=1$.

Case 2: If $a=2$ then $\frac{1}{b} = k+\frac{1}{2}$ but clearly $0\leq \frac{1}{b}\leq 1$ so $\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{2}$ hence $b=2$.

Case 3: If $a\geq 3$ then $\frac{1}{a}\leq \frac{1}{3}$ and so $\frac{1}{b}\geq \frac{2}{3}$ but there is no natural number $b$ satisfying this condition other than $b=1$ in this case $a=1$ as in Case 1. (because $\frac{1}{x}$ is decreasing and $\frac{1}{2}$ is already smaller).